# Designing pipeline system

Tags: c#, architecture, microservices, pipeline, system-design

### Background

I have set of tools\solution that can be combined together into a one single data processing\action flow.

Each unit on my flow do a calculation or do an action.

Example: `Solve equation` -> `send email`

In this example, the `Solve equation` unit is a type of calculation unit. While the `send email` unit is action.

The point that I have 100 different units that can be combined together on a different order.

### The Question

In order to solve this problem, I planning to create a data flow for my application. Each flow will implement this interface:

```
public interface IFlow
{
    public IUnit[] UnitsChain{get;}
    
    public void Start(string input);
}
```

While my unit will implement this interface:

```
public interface IUnit
{
    public string /*output*/ Process(string input);
}
```

Everything in this design sound doable, but also sounds like I "inventing the wheel" instead of using an existing solution that allow those option.

Looking to better solution to implement this kind of custom pipeline processing.

Thanks!

Comment: _"In order to solve this problem, I planning to create a data flow for my application."_ - guess what: Microsoft already did that! [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)

Comment: Also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/pipes-and-filters code: https://github.com/mspnp/cloud-design-patterns/tree/master/pipes-and-filters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Everything in this design sound doable, but also sounds like I "inventing the wheel" instead of using an existing solution that allow those option"*

Microsoft's own [DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) basically provides this functionality with very convenient options to parallelize steps etc.

Let's break it down:

### Solve an equation

That sounds like a job for a [TransformBlock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.transformblock-2?view=net-5.0).

You set it up to use a transformation method that will take an (let's call it) `TInput` type and produces `TOutput` (Result of Equation).

### Send an Email

I'd break this up into two more Blocks:

1. Transform `TOutput` to an Email
2. Send Email

So you have one more `Transformblock<TOutput , Email>`and one [`ActionBlock<Email>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.actionblock-1?view=net-5.0)

(I am using "Email" like a type here. It's just a placeholder. The exact type of course depends on Email Framework in use.)

### Put it all together

You then build your pipeline by "linking" `TransformBlock<TInput, TOutput>` => `TransformBlock<TOutput, Email>` => `ActionBlock<Email>`.

Having done that, you have set up a complete Pipeline to wich you can submit `TInput`s and the framework will take care of the rest. Each block can be [conveniently configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions?view=net-5.0) to for example process several `TInput` in parallel etc.

It also let's you decide if you want to use synchronous or asynchronous (Task/await) API.